# Line on screen only on Chrome tab

Tags: google-chrome, laptop, display, laptop-display, asus-laptop

There is a small vertical line that appears on my laptop screen, but only appears on Chrome and only when there is a certain amount of tabs open.

You can see it below, just to right of the close tab button and above the 'd' in the word below it.

[image]

If I add another tab, it disappears.  The line would have been just above the 'd' in the world below the tab.

[image]

This only ever appears on the tab on Chrome, if I re-size Chrome or move it around the screen it doesn't appear and does not appear on any other apps, or on the desktop.

IS this an issue with Chrome, my graphics card, or my screen?

Comment: Is Chrome up to date? Version `52.0.2743.116 m` is the latest.

Comment: yup, 52.0.2743.116 m (64-bit) here.